# JacksonAutoConfiguration is pulled in although excluded

Tags: spring-boot

I have a simple REST service which is using spring-boot-jersey. My Application looks like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {JacksonAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoAutoConfiguration.class, JmxAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)).run(args);
}

}
```

However if I start the service with `-Ddebug` I can see that these autoconfiguration classes are still pulled in:

```
JacksonAutoConfiguration
  - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper (OnClassCondition)

JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperAutoConfiguration
  - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper (OnClassCondition)

JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperAutoConfiguration#jacksonObjectMapper
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Why the contraption in the main method? Just use `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);`

Comment: do you think this causes the problem? :)

Comment: It might but it is at least cleaner. One thing I notice is a missing `@Configuration` on your `Application` class.

Comment: you don't need Configuration on Application, unless you want to use it as a @Configuration class meaning defining beans in them which I definitely don't want.

Comment: `@CompontScan` for instance will only be scanned when on a `@Configuration`. `@Configuration` is for marking a class as configuration class it doesn't say anything about the fact you MUSt include `@Bean` annotations.

Comment: that is just another way of defining beans in my book which as i said i don't want, i'm perfectly happy to have Application as a starter class and configurations in separate classes.

Comment: Then why do you have the `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on there in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The `HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration` imports the `JacksonAutoConfiguration`, so you have to exclude that one as well. Probably a bug really, but at least the workaround is obvious. Why did you want to exclude `JacksonAutoConfiguration` though?

Comment: We wanted to use our modified version of JsonMappingExceptionMapper.class, although since I asked the question I realized that this is registered by JacksonFeature. Thanks for your answer though - and yes regardless of the actual problem I think Autoconfigs should be independent and excludes shoud work for each of them.